# How to count days in which a product's quantity on hand was 0 for a month? in Odoo

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo, odoo-10

How to simply count days in which a product's quantity on hand was **0** for a month. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

/i'm trying query. But it's too complicated ^^/

Comment: That's actually not so easy. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post anything you have...  table structures, sample data, any code you have thus far

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to define "the day a product's quantity on hand is 0", becuase the quantity could change a lot during a day due to stock moves. It could be "the qty on hand is 0 in every minute of a day" or "the qty on hand is 0 at 23:59:59 of a day".

I think there are two approaches:

1. Calculate the qty on hand using `stock.move` across timeline and see how many 0s. This works well if you want to use computing power to replace disk storage usage and if you want to do the report now using existing data.
2. Create a new model to store qty on hand from `stock.quant` at a specific time point of a day. This is easier to code but only works for future reports and does not work well if you need to check multiple time points per day.

For the first approach, you can do SQL to get the quantity on hand at a **specific time point** calculated from `stock.move`.

If you don't care the location and just need the quantity on hand grouped by products:

```
WITH AGG AS
  (SELECT stock_move.product_id AS "PP",
          ROUND(stock_move.quantity_done / uom_uom.factor, 2) AS "Base_Qty_Done"
   FROM stock_move
   LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = stock_move.product_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON stock_move.product_uom = uom_uom.id
   WHERE product_template.type = 'product'
     AND stock_move.state = 'done'
     AND date <= '2020-01-01 07:00:00'
     UNION
    ALL
     SELECT stock_move.product_id AS "PP",
            - ROUND(stock_move.quantity_done / uom_uom.factor, 2) AS "Base_Qty_Done"
     FROM stock_move
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = stock_move.product_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON stock_move.product_uom = uom_uom.id WHERE product_template.type = 'product'
     AND stock_move.state = 'done'
     AND date <= '2020-01-01 07:00:00' ),
     CALC AS
  (SELECT AGG."PP",
          sum(AGG."Base_Qty_Done") "Base QoH"
   FROM AGG
   GROUP BY AGG."PP")
SELECT product_product.default_code "Reference",
       CALC."Base QoH" "Qty Calculated From Stock Move",
       uom_category.name "Base UoM Of"
FROM CALC
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = CALC."PP"
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON product_template.uom_id = uom_uom.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_category ON uom_category.id = uom_uom.category_id
WHERE CALC."Base QoH" = 0
ORDER BY CALC."PP"
```

If you need the quantity on hand per product per location:

```
WITH AGG AS
  (SELECT stock_move.product_id AS "PP",
          stock_move.location_dest_id AS "Loc",
          ROUND(stock_move.quantity_done / uom_uom.factor, 2) AS "Base_Qty_Done"
   FROM stock_move
   LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = stock_move.product_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
   LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON stock_move.product_uom = uom_uom.id
   WHERE product_template.type = 'product'
     AND stock_move.state = 'done'
     AND date <= '2020-01-01 07:00:00'
     UNION
    ALL
     SELECT stock_move.product_id AS "PP",
            stock_move.location_id AS "Loc", - ROUND(stock_move.quantity_done / uom_uom.factor, 2) AS "Base_Qty_Done"
     FROM stock_move
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = stock_move.product_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON stock_move.product_uom = uom_uom.id WHERE product_template.type = 'product'
     AND stock_move.state = 'done'
     AND date <= '2020-01-01 07:00:00' ),
     CALC AS
  (SELECT AGG."PP",
          AGG."Loc",
          sum(AGG."Base_Qty_Done") "Base QoH"
   FROM AGG
   GROUP BY AGG."PP",
            AGG."Loc")
SELECT product_product.default_code "Reference",
       stock_location.name "Location",
       CALC."Base QoH" "Qty Calculated From Stock Move",
       uom_category.name "Base UoM Of"
FROM CALC
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_product ON product_product.id = CALC."PP"
LEFT OUTER JOIN stock_location ON stock_location.id = CALC."Loc"
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_template ON product_template.id = product_product.product_tmpl_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_uom ON product_template.uom_id = uom_uom.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN uom_category ON uom_category.id = uom_uom.category_id
WHERE CALC."Base QoH" = 0
ORDER BY CALC."PP"
```

Change all `'2020-01-01 07:00:00'` in the query to your desired time point and repeat for all points on your timeline (if just one time thing, you may hand-craft the report with SQL and Excel, if not, write some code).

For the second approach, the query to get quantity on hand per product per location is easy.

```
SELECT stock_quant.product_id "PP ID", 
       stock_quant.location_id "Location ID", 
       Sum(stock_quant.quantity) "QoH"
FROM   stock_quant 
GROUP  BY stock_quant.location_id, 
          stock_quant.product_id
```

You will need to write a new model with a schedueld task to store the data at pre-defined interval.

I'd recommend method 1, it's more work but uses less disk space and you can do reports on any time period including the past.

Comment: Sorry, that's not the result I wanted.